# Showing $(n+1)^n<e^nn!$ by induction

Tags: inequality, induction, exponential-function, factorial

> Show $(n+1)^n<e^nn!$

I know why that would be the case using general knowledge and a bit of substitution but am clueless on how to prove it.

Answer (score 3):

- The inequality is true for $n = 1$ because $(1+1)^1 = 2$ and $e^1 1! = e > 2$.
- Suppose it is true for some fixed $n$. Multiplying both sides by $(n+1)$, we obtain
  $$
  (n+1)^{n+1} < e^n (n+1)!
  $$
  Finally, notice that $(n+2)^{n+1}=(n+1)^{n+1}\left(1+\frac{1}{n+1}\right)^{n+1} < (n+1)^{n+1}\cdot e^1$, so that
  $$
  (n+2)^{n+1} < e^{n+1}(n+1)!
  $$

Comment: I don't have 15 rep so I'm going appreciate your help and say thanks here.

Comment: @Siméon Just FYI, voting indeed requires 15 rep. But accepting does not. Too bad the OP did not realize this.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Consider the simple factorization. 
\begin{equation}
(n+1)^{n} = n^{n} \left( 1 + \frac{1}{n} \right)^{n}.
\end{equation}