# How to prove this inequality $(\frac{n+1}{e})^{n} < n! < e(\frac{n+1}{e})^{n+1}$?

Tags: analysis, inequality, exponential-function, factorial

$\Bigl(\frac{n+1}{e}\Bigr)^{n} < n! < e\Bigl(\cfrac{n+1}{e}\Bigr)^{n+1}$

Comment: Have you tried anything at all?

Comment: Related questions: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/624770/showing-n1nenn-by-induction and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/389516/how-to-prove-fracn1enne-fracn1en1-without-integrating-m

Answer (score 2):

Both inequalities boil down to showing that for any $m \in \mathbb N$:

$$\int_{1}^{m} \ln(x)dx \ge \sum_{k=1}^{m-1} \ln(k)$$

And:

$$\int_{1}^{m} \ln(x) dx \le \sum_{k =1}^{m} \ln(k)$$

Both might be done by induction. The first one is easy to establish. For the second one, use:

- $$\int_{1}^{m} \ln(x) dx = \int_{1}^{m-1} \ln(x) dx + \int_{m-1}^{m} \ln(x)dx$$
- MVT for integrals.
- $\ln$ is increasing.

Comment: +1 As you probably know, this is the first step in one way ot developing Stirling's Formula.

Answer (score 2):

We wish to show that $n!$ is bounded by the inequalities

$$\left(\frac{n+1}{e}\right)^{n}<n!<e\left(\frac{n+1}{e}\right)^{n+1}\tag1$$

We will prove these inequalities using mathematical induction.

---

Let's start with the left-hand side inequality in $(1)$.  First, we establish a base case.  For $n=2$, we see that $2!>\left(\frac{3}{e}\right)^2$.  Therefore, we assume that for some $n$, we have $\left(\frac{n+1}{e}\right)^{n}<n!$.  Now, for $n+1$ we write

$$\begin{align}
(n+1)!&=(n+1)n!\\\\
&>(n+1)\left(\frac{n+1}{e}\right)^{n}\\\\
&=\left(\frac{n+2}{e}\right)^{n+1}\,\left[e\left(\frac{n+1}{n+2}\right)^{n+1}\right]\\\\
&=\left(\frac{n+2}{e}\right)^{n+1}\,\frac{e}{\left(1+\frac{1}{n+1}\right)^{n+1}}\\\\
&>\left(\frac{n+2}{e}\right)^{n+1}
\end{align}$$

where in the last inequality, we used $\left(1+\frac{1}{n+1}\right)^{n+1}<e$.

This concludes the proof by mathematical induction.

---

Next, we analyze the right-hand side inequality in $(1)$.  First, we establish a base case.  For $n=2$, we see that $2!<e\left(\frac{3}{e}\right)^2$.  Therefore, we assume that for some $n$, we have $e\left(\frac{n+1}{e}\right)^{n+1}>n!$.  Now, for $n+1$ we write

$$\begin{align}
(n+1)!&=(n+1)n!\\\\
&<(n+1)e\left(\frac{n+1}{e}\right)^{n+1}\\\\
&=e\left(\frac{n+2}{e}\right)^{n+2}\,\left[e\left(\frac{n+1}{n+2}\right)^{n+2}\right]\\\\
&=e\left(\frac{n+2}{e}\right)^{n+2}\,\left[e\left(1-\frac{1}{n+2}\right)^{n+2}\right]\\\\
&<e\left(\frac{n+2}{e}\right)^{n+2}
\end{align}$$

where in the last inequality, we used $\left(1-\frac{1}{n+2}\right)^{n+2}<e^{-1}$.

This concludes the proof by mathematical induction.

Comment: Why the down vote??  I don't understand how anyone would nearly instantaneously give this proof a down vote.  The vote came just a moment after it was posted and the voter left no comment to suggest a reason.  Incredulous!

Comment: Pretty funny. I refreshed to see the new answer, it was as if the down vote was automatically attached to it. It would be more helpful if down voters can explain their reason for doing so, instead of running away like this.

Comment: @BolzWeir Has this happened to you before?  Whenever I see others whose sincere and appropriate answers receive an anonymous down vote, I neutralize it to provide a sense of balance.  I don't understand the trigger happy down voter mentality.

Comment: @Dr.MV nice work. Vote up ...

Comment: @johannesvalks Thank you!  Very much appreciated.  I am recovering at home from a surgery $2$ weeks ago and your comment means a lot.

Answer (score 0):

By Stirling formula, there exists a number $0<\theta<1$ such that $$n!=\sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac ne\right)^n e^{\frac \theta{12n}}.$$ So we have to prove that

$$\Bigl(\frac{n+1}{e}\Bigr)^{n} < \frac{1}{n+1}\sqrt{2\pi (n+1)}\left(\frac {n+1}e\right)^{n+1} e^{\frac \theta{12(n+1)}}< e\Bigl(\cfrac{n+1}{e}\Bigr)^{n+1},$$ that is

$$\frac{e}{n+1} <\frac{1}{n+1}\sqrt{2\pi (n+1)} e^{\frac \theta{12(n+1)}}< e,$$

which holds (for $n\ge 1$) because

$$e<3<\sqrt{4\pi}\le \sqrt{2\pi (n+1)}$$ and

$$\frac{1}{n+1}\sqrt{2\pi (n+1)} e^{\frac \theta{12(n+1)}}<
\sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{n+1}} e^{\frac 1{24}}\le 
\sqrt{\pi} e^{\frac 1{24}}< e,$$ because of the following sequence

$$\pi^{\frac 12}<e^{\frac {23}{24}}$$

$$\pi^{12}<e^{20}$$

$$\pi^{3}<33<53<e^{4}<e^5.$$